# Include doxygen into existing project

Tags: import

I work on an small project. For this project I write an small report using LaTeX with predefined layout etc.

The source code itself is documented using comments in doxygen style.

How do I need to modify my LaTeX Project (or Doxygen config) that I just need to to import/subimport the generated TeX files for each sourcefile?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is doxygen style? What is doxygen? Not all people here do know that program. Please explain better your problem, for example by adding an doxygen and an tex code ...

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.